# For what value of a will the system have no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the following system of linear equations

```
2x + 2y + 3z    = 0        (1)
4x + 8y + 12z   = -4       (2)
6x + 2y + az    = 4        (3)
```

Is the following system always consistent no matter what the value of a is ?
By applying the row operation, I find that R3 of the matrix is

```
0x + 0y + (a-3)z = 0
```

Therefore, if the value of a is 3, the system have infinitely many solutions.
And if the value of a != 3, the system have a unique solution.

```
Does it mean that this system must have solution no matter what the value of $a$ is?
```

If no, how can I find the value of $a$ such that the system has no solution? Thank You.

Comment: Do you know linear space? I would like to answer based on your reply.

Comment: No, I only learn the method of row operations

Comment: I am studying the math for economics ,therefore i do not know much about the method

Comment: Before I answer, there is something make me confused. What is your problem? It seems like that you have had an answer to your question. _"Therefore, if the value of a is 3, the system have infinitely many solutions. And if the value of a != 3, the system have a unique solution."_

Comment: I do not know much about the system of linear equations. Is it possible that no matter the value of a is, the system is always have solution? Under the above system, is it true that the system will never have no solution , no matter what the value of a is? Thank You.

Comment: Are you saying about some general case? (i.e. not only the system in your post)

Comment: For the above system, is it true that the system will never have no solution , no matter what the value of a is? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true for your specific system but false for general systems.

Counterexample:
$$
\begin{align}
x&+&y&+&z&=&1 \\
x&+&2y&+&3z&=&10 \\
x&+&3y&+&4z&=&11+\epsilon
\end{align}
$$
for $\epsilon \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I only solved the general systems before, I don`t know the system can always have solution. Thank You.